# jQuery - how to decode an AJAX output and place it in a drop-down select menu?

Tags: jquery

I have a regular text box that people type input to. On keyup, I want to do a like query in the db and see if there are any matches. If there are some matches, I want to display them as choices for the person to choose before they finish typing.

This would work just like in stackOverflow, the functionality for choosing tags works.

How can I do this? Right now I am returning the choice data encoded in json from my ajax to the jQuery code, but I don't know how to loop through it and make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.it/demos/autocomplete).

Check the documentation, it is fairly flexible and you can make it work almost however you like (such as what you described).